# Flutter chart series legend id too long

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-layout

i used charts_flutter to make a groupbar chart, i want to create graph and show the legend, but the legend text is too long and i don't know how to wrap it so it can fit the screen

is there a way to wrap that id text somehow?

i tried this tutorial
https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/legends/series_legend_options

my chart is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HASF.png)